# Effect of SMOTE on Random Forest and Logistic Regression on a Cell2Cell churn dataset

Tags: python, logistic-regression, random-forest, smote

I am doing an analysis of the effect of SMOTE on the performance of Random Forest and Logistic Regression. I have the following data from [kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/jpacse/datasets-for-churn-telecom?select=cell2celltrain.csv). The data consists of around 50000 observations and 58 variables. I trained four models on it:

1. Random Forest
2. Random Forest with SMOTE
3. Logistic Regression
4. Logistic Regression with SMOTE

I got the following results:

[image]

−  = sqrt( × y)

**Question:**
What causes the Logistic Regression to improve a lot with SMOTE and what causes the Random Forest to **not** improve so much?

My thought was that it may be because of the high dimensionality but I would expect the Random Forest to do better than the Logistic Regression.